# HAProxy - Redirecting URL to different URL

Tags: url, redirect, haproxy

I am looking for a HAProxy solution where we want to translate the incoming url to completely different url, I have gone through the documentation and implemented where backend is using server ip and port.
Kindly suggest if someone achieve this before?

Ask-
www.original.com/test --> www.wanaBeoriginal.co.in/umenhum

Comment: Need to sort out some terminology here - do you mean you want your proxy to issue an HTTP redirect when it receives a request for the first URL to tell the browser to request the second URL, or do you want to proxy to transparently fetch the second URL and return the content to the browser?

Comment: It should go to second url and fetch the result